# Finding the first two occurences of a variable in an adjacent column within dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to solve a problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I currently have a table containing transaction data for each shoe brand / colour combination, we can call this table `transactions`.

This is a sample of the data in the table, but I have thousands of these transactions across brands. The table has 5-6 more shoe brands, with multiple transactions at different prices. The color column always has a value of either **white** or **black**.

| shoe_brand (fct) | color (fct) | transaction_date (POSIXct) | price (dbl) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | White | 2019-05-27 01:19:28 | 200 |
| Nike | White | 2019-05-28 14:51:09 | 500 |
| Nike | White | 2019-05-30 16:41:05 | 600 |
| Nike | Black | 2019-05-31 20:30:48 | 350 |
| Nike | Black | 2019-06-05 18:22:19 | 220 |
| Adidas | White | 2019-06-12 13:26:59 | 540 |
| Adidas | Black | 2019-06-23 00:28:45 | 335 |
| Adidas | White | 2019-07-02 04:26:19 | 695 |

I am trying to find the first transaction of each combination of `shoe_brand` and `color` (i.e. nike, white and nike, black), and have tried using the `match` and `unique`, but still can't find a solution that retrieves the first two (rather than one) occurrence.

Sorry for any formatting issues, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping we could use `top_n`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(shoe_brand, color, transaction_date) %>%
  group_by(shoe_brand, color) %>%
  top_n(1)
```

Output:

```
  shoe_brand color transaction_date price   
  <chr>      <chr> <date>           <time>  
1 Adidas     Black 2019-06-23       00:28:45
2 Adidas     White 2019-06-12       13:26:59
3 Nike       Black 2019-05-31       20:30:48
4 Nike       White 2019-05-30       16:41:05
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply TarJae! Worked flawlessly, didn't think to use the top_n function in this way. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

We may use `arrange` and then `slice_head` (assuming that the 'transaction_date' is `POSIXct`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    arrange(shoe_brand, color, transaction_date) %>%
    group_by(shoe_brand, color) %>%
    slice_head(n = 2)
```

Comment: Cheers for the response Akrun! However, this code results it it pulling the first two rows for both white and black shoes (i.e. the first two rows of **nike, white** + the first two rows of **nike, black.**

Tried out TarJae's suggestion below, and worked well for me!